# Detect Twilio <Say/> command has finished

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-voice

In the following set of instructions:

```xml
<Response>
  <Gather action="...">
    <Say>Hello</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

is there a way to detect when `<Say/>` instruction has finished?

One way I have tried to solve this is to add `</Redirect>` at the end:

```xml
<Response>
  <Gather action="...">
    <Say>Hello</Say>
  </Gather>
  <Redirect>https://example.com/say-finished</Redirect>
</Response>
```

However, `<Redirect/>` will be executed only after `<Gather/>` has finished which will happen after gather `timeout` value.

Comment: Can you please explain the purpose of the redirect? I have the feeling it might make more sense to add this snippet in the "actions" callback

Comment: We would like to detect when `<Say/>` command has finished.

Comment: @IObert do you have an example of how that can be done with "actions" callback instead?

Comment: Why are you interested when `<Say/>`is done? It often makes more sense to wait until the user replied to the prompt by pressing a key.

Comment: We have a queue of messages that we want to Say to the user. Messages in the queue are added async, so we cannot just use multiple `<Say/>` within one set of instructions. We have to somehow wait until the previous `<Say/>` has finished and after that send new `<Say/>`. Do you see any other way to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to embed these `<Say/>` in the `<Gather/>` tag then. Gather will wait for input and then redirect the call to the `action` URL.

Comment: This is a requirement as well, for users to be able to interrupt `<Say/>`, we cannot just skip this either. Is there no way both can be archived?

Comment: @IObert is it correct that it's not possible to do this?

Comment: Tbh, I don't understand. The question whether Say is interruptible doesn't seem to be related to how Gather works with the action param.

Comment: The question is how can we know when Say (specifically Say not Gather) has finished (Say has to be still wrapped in Gather tho for the reason I mentioned). Is that possible or perhaps there is no way to do it?

Comment: For the Say to be interruptible by user's voice/DTMF it has to be wrapped in Gather.

Comment: "For the Say to be interruptible by user's voice/DTMF it has to be wrapped in Gather.", this is correct. I'm not clear why you want to know when it's finished. This shouldn't matter because the user can always hit the keys early.

Comment: We might need to say another message right after first one has finished. That message is not available when we send initial instructions.

Comment: Why is it not available after sending the first instructions? Or do you mean you want to have a second gather with a different say that the users hears **after** providing the first input?

Comment: This is just a constraint that we have, not sure it's relevant for the solution.

Comment: It's hard to help you when I don't understand the full scenario. Usually, it's enough to dynamically calculate the say of the second gather. It's hard for me to image a reason why it makes sense to update the first one without having any new information.

Comment: I provided as much information as I can, but it's just a use-case that we have, we don't have a second message available when we send the first one. That's the scenario. Is there anything in Twilio that can accommodate it?

Answer (score 0):

After our discussion above, this is the best answer I can provide. But I would recommend to speak to professional services or a partner and explain them your full use-case to find the ideal solution.

You can start with the nested `<Say>` in a `<Gather>`element and if you want to update the text, update the entire TwiML of that call. For this, you need to know the id of the call and estimate (or better measure) how much time is passed since the call started to avoid interrupting your `<Say>`.

You can use this method from the SDK to modify TwiML of [ongoing calls](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/tutorials/how-to-modify-calls-in-progress).

```js
client.calls('CAXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
      .update({twiml: '<Response><Say>Ahoy there</Say></Response>'})
      .then(call => console.log(call.to));
```

Comment: But how do I know when the Say has finished, that's the issue?

Comment: There's no way of getting to notified about that. You could try to estimate when it's done, e.g. 7 seconds after the call started or so. I know this answer is not perfect but I'm afraid this is all I can provide with the information I have.